# How to declare toString method in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to declare an util method which converts a byte array to a string, in `java`, it looks like:

```
public static String toString(byte[] byteArray)
```

Same in `kotlin`:

```
fun ByteArray.toString(): String
```

But we know `toString` is a member method of type `Any`(`Object`), it will hide `ByteArray.toString()`. Is there any idea or advice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to use a different name for your function. For example, in the Kotlin standard library you'll find `ByteArray.contentToString()`, which is an alternative to `toString()` that displays the content of the array rather than the address of the array itself.

```kotlin
val b = byteArrayOf(0, 1, 2)
println(b.toString()) // [B@5451c3a8
println(b.contentToString()) // [0, 1, 2]
```

Notice how the name `contentToString` describes what the function does differently from the normal `ByteArray.toString()` function.

If you need to do something different from both `toString()` and `contentToString()`, you could try to come up with a function name that describes what your function does differently from the existing functions.